# Changing a file object's name in React.js state

Tags: reactjs

Good Day!
Using React and [react-dropzone](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone/) and now [immutability helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper/)

Users can drop cvs files in , a list appears with file names in input boxes so they can change filenames if needed.

The filelist is set as

```
 onDrop = (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles, e) => {
     this.setState({
         files: acceptedFiles
    });
 }
```

setState({files: acceptedFiles })

I have the inputs onChange wired to an onChangeHandler function.

I quickly encountered error of read-only for name on `#<File>` object and came across advice to use update from immutability helpers.

So I came up with this

```
onChangeHandler = (event) =>{
  let id = event.target.id; 
  this.setState(update(this.state.files[id], {name: {$set: event.target.value }})); 
}
```

However upon editing the file name in the input that now produces

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'File': 2 arguments required, but only 0 present.`

I get what that means just have no idea how to modify the update() to satisfy the File recreation.

Or is there a more suitable approach?

Thank you if anyone can chime in.

Comment: What if you had a separate array on state that kept track of the file names and this would be what you display on screen? This way when a user changes a file name, they are not changing the actual file name at all. If you were to need the changed file names to save that server side, you can send the array of file names to the server as well. I am making a lot of assumptions here, so this is just a thought really.

Comment: "You can't change the name on a File object in JS." is a comment I got from github... so that makes perfect sense to keep a separate array that can be referenced when writing... Thanks

Comment: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File) for reference it anyone else needs to know all File object properties are read only